# XPath to select all href's in element

Tags: html, xpath

i have a trouble with XPath. I have a HTML page with complicated structure and i want to select ALL href's elements in particular div, regardless of the depth of nesting.
Why next code doesn't work and what can I do to fix?

```
//*[@id='some_id']//*//a
```

Comment: Are you trying to select `a` elements or `href` attributes? Those are two different things…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Matching `@href` attributes

Select all `@href` attributes, not all anchor tags.

```
//*[@id='some_id']//@href
```

If you only want to match the `@href` attributes of anchor tags, go for this query, which selects all anchor tags inside that "some_id"-element, and then their `@href` tags.

```
//*[@id='some_id']//a/@href
```

#### `//` and the `descendant-or-self`-axis

I'm not sure what you wanted to achieve with the `.//*//a` construct. This is an abbreviation for

```
./descendant-or-self::node()/child::*/descendant-or-self::node()/child::a
```

so there must be some element in-between. If the anchor tag is directly contained within the `@id='some_id'`-element, it will not be found, for example for this input:

```
<div id='some_id'><a href="foo">bar</a></div>
```

`//*[@id='some_id']//a` would have matched this element.

Answer (score 0):

`//` addresses the entire descendant axis, so this is sufficient:

```
//*[@id='some_id']//a
```

Otherwise, you wouldn't get `a` elements that are immediate descendants of the element addressed with `//*[@id='some_id']`.  (If your environment recognizes `id` attributes as being IDs, you can also address this element with `id('some_id')`.)

But your problem is likely to be something different.  `//a` usually addresses all `a` elements in the null namespace.  Possibly your `a` elements aren't in the null namespace but in the XHTML namespace.  You could match them like

```
//*[@id='some_id']//*[local-name()='a' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']
```

or, if you only have to expect HTML elements anyway

```
//*[@id='some_id']//*[local-name()='a']
```

or in XPath 2.0 even simpler

```
//*[@id='some_id']//*:a
```

Depending on your environment, you can also register a namespace prefix so that you can do something like

```
//*[@id='some_id']//html:a
```

in both XPath 1.0 and 2.0.